# ggvis R -how to display data in descending order?

Tags: r, ggvis

I am using the below code, to create a bar chart in descending order for V1:

```
AvgOverallkeyword<- arrange(AvgOverallkeyword,desc(V1))
ggvis(AvgOverallkeyword,x=~Keyword,y=~V1)%>% layer_bars(fill:="orange")

I am getting attached chart instead[1]
  AvgOverallkeyword is in below format:
 Keyword    V1
 BWB        67.92
 Ebill      2.26
 LI Ver     2.16
 Start Svc  1.85
```

What am I doing wrong, it might be something really stupid !!

Comment: Unable to create link for the image !!

Comment: I wonder if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082021/r-ggvis-ordering-axis) helps you.